# Cloudformation Outputs: Template format error: Every Value member must be a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

Received this error message from Cloudformation after adding output block below:

`Template format error: Every Value member must be a string.`

```
Outputs:
  NetFwEndpointIds:
    Description: Array for Network FW Endpoint Ids
    Value: !GetAtt NetFw.EndpointIds
    Export:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-EndpointIds'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-networkfirewall-firewall.html

`EndpointIds`

The unique IDs of the firewall endpoints for all of the subnets that you attached to the firewall. The subnets are not listed in any particular order. For example: ["us-west-2c:vpce-111122223333", "us-west-2a:vpce-987654321098", "us-west-2b:vpce-012345678901"].

Looking for a workaround to share these endpoints across nested stack templates. Thanks!

Received this error message from Cloudformation after adding output block below:

Template format error: Every Value member must be a string.

Outputs:
NetFwEndpointIds:
Description: Array for Network FW Endpoint Ids
Value: !GetAtt NetFw.EndpointIds
Export:
Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-EndpointIds'
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-networkfirewall-firewall.html

EndpointIds

The unique IDs of the firewall endpoints for all of the subnets that you attached to the firewall. The subnets are not listed in any particular order. For example: ["us-west-2c:vpce-111122223333", "us-west-2a:vpce-987654321098", "us-west-2b:vpce-012345678901"].

Looking for a workaround to share these endpoints across nested stack templates. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the array to string using join, like this:

```
Outputs:
  NetFwEndpointIds:
      Description: Array for Network FW Endpoint Ids
      Value: !Join
          - ','
          - !GetAtt NetFw.EndpointIds
      Export:
        Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-EndpointIds"
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) to convert your list of ids to a string.